# Display Original Image on Node View when using Image Crop Module

Tags: 7, media

I have an image field on a content type using Image with Cropping.

The cropped image is used on a block view and a page view, but on the actual single item node view I need to have the original full image.

Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this, not so elegant  but it works.

In the theme file (page--TYPE.tpl.php) use the following code to get the file object:

```
$file = _imagefield_crop_file_to_crop($node->FIELD["und"][0]["fid"]);
```

This will load the original file used for the cropping.

Answer (score 1):

If the Image field does not support a "un-cropped original" style on the field's View page, then it looks like a second image field (without crop) would be in order. You would then use the un-cropped field on the single node view, and the cropped one in the view and block.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid using two image fields.